# Facebook Login - Firebase V3

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase

I am playing around with the new version of Firebase SDK and just wanted to add Facebook Login. I'm able to log in users via Facebook, but this does not create a record in the realtime database. In the previous version of Firebase, it was explicitly explained that login did not create a user reference in the database, and that we had to save it ourselves, in this version it appears it automatically creates the record, but this does not work for me. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
        loginButton.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    print("successfullyAuthenticated")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("logged out")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't create the record in your Firebase database, it creates the user in your Firebase proyect and it appears in the authentication panel. Then you are responsible of store it into the database with the user data you may want.

Comment: alright, slight misunderstanding from my side then, cheers! 
I'm gonna go for the old method with Facebook Manager and not Facebook Login button.

Answer (score 4):

if you look carefully to your code

you will see it will crash if someone click on cancel button or Done button when the facebook confirm page saying "you have already authorized ..yourappname "

to obtain that page logout from facebook and try to login again

hope it helps you to have a better code ... i m also working on the new firebase ...

avoid it like this

```
        guard let accessToken:FBSDKAccessToken? = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() else{

            return
        }

        if accessToken!.tokenString != nil {

            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken((accessToken?.tokenString)!)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
```

Comment: thank you for this addition, it indeed throws a fatal error if not implemented.